# How to start for Magento for a Drupal Developer?

Tags: php, magento, drupal, content-management-system

I am drupal developer and working in it for 4 years. Now i want to go for Magento, Can anyone guide me how to get started and go for it.

Any links/resources will be helpful.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: As interesting as this question is, recommendation questions are not on-topic on Stack Overflow. I'd advise finding resources via a search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have prior knowledge of Drupal than it would not be a problem learning magento.

For the detail knowledge i will recommend you to learn in the flow below.This will help you learn quickly and learn more efficiently.

Divide the learning into 3 parts:

1. Magento is a powerful CMS so there are many things you can do without touching the codes, so at first be familiar with the admin panel.
2. Next part is layouts. I can't explain much because it is vast but i would recommend the youtube channel of **leveluptuts** for the layout part.Its not and advertisement but I also developed my concept from there.It gives detail knowledge.You can follow any as your wish.
3. And last is module development.After you have good knowledge of both of the above than you can start with the module development part.There are many tutorials available for this.

In this pattern you can learn more efficiently(in my opinion).

Hope you will do great.

Comment: Thanks Navin, It is good to hear that and nice. In this way i have modulate the course.

Comment: Its always my pleasure to share my experience.

Answer (score 0):

i dont have much experience about drupal. but   drupal is easier to work with than Magento in general . but on the e-commerce side of things Magento is far more powerful and mature than Drupal commerce.

if you haven't Magento  knowlage  better read 
this
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento

normally  every documentation very ruff to learn use google , blog , youtube

this is better normally i follow

http://alanstorm.com/category/magento

Comment: Thank you for this help. I will read them and i expect a good knowledge from them. "Experience doesn't matter its all about will power and learning.".